# React js - Difference between "const example = () => {}" and "function example () {}"

Tags: reactjs, function, constants

I have built this code:

```
const example = () => {

  console.log("test");

}
```

```
function example() {
 
  console.log("test");

}
```

Seeing as their output and use are identical, is there any significant difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing i could find is about Hoisting, if you use some component before declaring it, you should use function so your linter wouldn't throw an error.

Like this

```
 const App = () => (
    <>
      <MyComponent />
      <AlsoMyComponent />
    </>
)
// I like to keep my components at the bottom

function MyComponent() {}

function AlsoMyComponent() {}
```

Check this out: https://dev.to/ugglr/react-functional-components-const-vs-function-2kj9